# How to append CSV file using CSVPrinter in Spring Batch Job

Tags: java, spring, csv, groovy, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job that needs to write location information to csv files.
As of now, I have a long list of locations that I have to write down into csv file.

the issue is I need to have only one csv file. but when this job runs, it writes the only last batch to the csv file. and I did some investigation and realize that it is not only the last batch but it is over-writing.

I have to use CSV printer as below and generate only one csv file that contains all the locations info. I was looking for some function or flag that I can call with CSVPrinter.
Unfortunately, I still could not figure this out.

Can someone help me sort this out with minimum change possible?

FYI, I am using Groovy as language.

```
@Component
@EnableContextResourceLoader
class LocationWriter implements ItemEriter<Location> {
  @Autowired
  ResourceLoader resourceLoader

  @Resource
  FileProperties fileProperties

  @Override
  void write(List<? extends Location> items) throws Exception {
    WritableResource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("s3://${fileProperties.bucket}/${fileProperties.outputLocation}")
  
    resource = (WritableResource)resource
    OutputStreamWriter writre = new OutputStreamWriter(resource.getOutputStream())
    
    printCSV(writer, items)

  }


  static void printCSV(OutputSreamWriter writer, List<Location> summaries) {
    new CSVPrinter(
      writer,
      CSVFormat.DEFAULT
        .withDelimiter('|' as char)
        .withHeader("id", "address", "city")
    ).withCloseable { CSVPrinter csvPrinter -> 
      summaries.each { Location location ->
        csvPrinter.printRecord(
          location.id
          location.address
          location.city
        )   
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem first. What is the input to your job? Why is it writing only the last batch? What is its expected output?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are working with aws s3

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=540395

It is not possible to append to an existing S3 object